# Defines inside a C Project

Tags: c

Often we see defines in the .h file like

```
  #ifndef _XX_H
 #define _XX_
  #ifdef __YY
  #include <yy.h>
 #endif
#endif
```

But where does _XX_H got defined? If it''s been defined. Could it be defined in another .h file?   Could be defined by the some files not generated by the programmer?

Another in this case if I want to __XX_H in my .h file how do I do that.

```
#define _XX_H
```

like that?

Comment: It's just the standard way of preventing multiple inclusion of a given header. It's usually called an "include guard".

Comment: You provide less information about xx.h than needed so you wont get an answer.

Comment: In your above example, _XX_ should be _XX_H and is probably a typo if it indeed appears in the header as you have it.  It is an include guard.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct in that it should include the "_H".  General form of an include guard:

```
#ifndef _FILE_H
#define _FILE_H

//INSERT CODE

#endif //_FILE_H
```

This format allows you to include the header in multiple files without defining/including anything within the header file twice

Comment: Names starting with `_[A-Z]` are reserved for any use, prefer `FILE_H` to `_FILE_H`.

Answer (score 4):

The snippet in your post has two problems with [*inclusion guards*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard):

- **`_XX_H` definition is checked, but `_XX_` is defined** - this is likely a typo - such guard does not "guard" anything. You should fix this to `#define _XX_H`
- **Definition of `__YY` inclusion guard is checked outside `yy.h`** - this is a very bad pattern: it is aimed at optimizing inclusions by preventing the opening of the `<yy.h>` by looking at its *private* inclusion guard. This practice makes your builds very fragile. If the authors of `yy.h` decided to guard their includes with `_YY_H` instead of `__YY`, the guard inside your header would fail.